# Outputting HTML ASCII codes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

HTML codes are not printing in angular js ng-repeat.
when i have an ascii code like '&' in the text it is printing the raw and not printing related symbol.

printing as

```
me &amp; mom
```

required as

```
me & mom
```

Comment: checkout `ng-bind-html-unsafe`.  It will render html.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js